# How to use a button to submit a value in a cell, while focus remains in that cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Google Sheets... I have a cell, called PartNum, and a button (drawing) linked to a function. The user enters a number in PartNum cell then clicks the button which triggers the function to go do something with that value.

Problem is that .getValue() for that cell is never the value the user enters UNLESS the user first clicks out of the cell. And thats not intuitive. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Have you tried to force the cell's value to update by using `setActiveRange()` and/or `flush()`?

Comment: Chris, I never figured out how to do that either (just tried again with sinaraheneba's suggestions).  I would highly recommend looking at [making a sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs) to add a nice UI to a sheet.

Comment: a little bit of testing; it seems like the contents of the cell aren't sent to Google until the user enters it, so it's likely not possible to read, and probably not possible to force, from the server side. dw's suggestion of client-side UI seems like the best option

Comment: Thankjs guys. Right, so put the form fields in a sidebar UI with submit button, and use the spreadsheet just to display data. Sounds much better and fit for purpose, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Each time the user makes a change he needs to save the Spreadsheet to get the script running, he can do this by clicking outside the cell or pressing the enter key, for example. The value "is not" in the cell while is being written, and Apps Script can only read values from the Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue with a checkbox:
I Created a checkbox in cell C4 in sheet "Submitdata"
By klicking the checkbox the focus will change to another cell.
I added following code in onedit(e).

```
 function onEdit(e) { 
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var resultSheetName = ss.getSheetName();
  var r = spreadsheet.getActiveCell();
  var source_row = r.getRow();
  var source_column = r.getColumn()

  var Checkbox =       
     ss.getSheetByName("Submitdata").getRange("C4").getValue()
     if(Checkbox == true){    
     YourFunction()
  ss.getSheetByName("Submitdata").getRange("C4").setValue(false)
      }
   }
```